# JavaScript. Автоматическое нажатие кнопки

Tags: javascript, button

Есть приложение на JS. В нем есть кнопка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы она автоматически один раз нажималась, сразу после загрузки приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('SyncButton')[0].addEventListener('click', clickFunction, false);

function clickFunction() {
    alert('Helllo!');
}

// Вот что нужно:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName('SyncButton')[0].click();
});
```

```html
<button class="SyncButton">click</button>
```

Так же возможно вам может понадобится:

```
window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementsByClassName('SyncButton')[0].click();
};
```

Событие load на объекте window наступает, когда загрузилась вся страница, включая стили, картинки и другие ресурсы.